# Multiple Summernote Wysiwyg editor in one page have same placeholder

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4, editor, summernote

I am currently using summernote which is working well throughout my application, however I am experiencing a small issue where I have 2 featured in one page.  I find that the placeholder in the second editor, is inheriting that of the first.  Is there an easy way round this, without creating wysiwyg-editor1 and wysiwyg-editor2?

```
editor = $('[data-toggle="wysiwyg-editor"]');

default_options = {
   minHeight: 400,
   styleTags: ['p', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3',],
   toolbar: [
        ['cleaner', ['cleaner']],
        ['insert', ['table', 'link']],
        ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
        ['font', ['strikethrough', 'superscript', 'subscript']],
        ['para', ['ul', 'ol']]
    ],
    placeholder: $(editor).attr('placeholder'),
    cleaner:{
        action: 'paste',
        newline: '<p></p>',
        keepClasses: true
    },
    prettifyHtml: true,
    disableDragAndDrop: true,
};

editor.summernote(default_options);


<textarea data-toggle="wysiwyg-editor" name="intro" placeholder="Provide an introduction"></textarea>
<textarea data-toggle="wysiwyg-editor" name="description" placeholder="Provide a description"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
editor_intro = $('[name="intro"]');
editor_description = $('[name="description"]');

    default_options = {
       minHeight: 400,
       styleTags: ['p', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3',],
       toolbar: [
            ['cleaner', ['cleaner']],
            ['insert', ['table', 'link']],
            ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
            ['font', ['strikethrough', 'superscript', 'subscript']],
            ['para', ['ul', 'ol']]
        ],
        cleaner:{
            action: 'paste',
            newline: '<p></p>',
            keepClasses: true
        },
        prettifyHtml: true,
        disableDragAndDrop: true,
    };

    default_options.placeholder = $(editor_intro).attr('placeholder');
    editor_intro.summernote(default_options);

    default_options.placeholder = $(editor_description).attr('placeholder');
    editor_description.summernote(default_options);


    <textarea data-toggle="wysiwyg-editor" name="intro" placeholder="Provide an introduction"></textarea>
    <textarea data-toggle="wysiwyg-editor" name="description" placeholder="Provide a description"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks, I did try something similar myself however the issue I have is that I also use  summernote on other pages in my application.  The default_options etc being defined in an include.